# Can I use the linear assignment solver to solve a generalized assignment problem?

Tags: python, or-tools

I would like to know if is possible to use the linear assignment solver to solve a generalized assignment problem. If it's possible, there is a parameter that I have to configure in the solver?

I took a look in the Google OR-Tools documentation, but I didn't found nothing mentioning that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You need to use the linear wrapper or the CP-SAT solver for this.